# How do i make the two nodes doubly linked? after some debugging i found that in Create(...) -> in else, there is something wrong with (*H)->next=...;

Tags: c, linked-list, doubly-linked-list

I have a school project in which I have to make such a menu to handle a double linked list with float content, but i have massive trouble making it double-linked,and after some debugging it looks like its all (*H)->next...'s fault, (apart from mine),when i get a new_node, i make its 'next' part point to the head's adress, and head's 'prev' part point to the new_node's adress, and then making head's adress that of new_node, thus head, becoming actually the head.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct node {
   char data;
    struct node *next;
    struct node *prev;
};

void Create(struct node **H,char  val) {
    struct node *new_node;
    new_node=malloc(1*sizeof(struct node));
    new_node->data=val;
    if(new_node==NULL){
        printf("RIP");
        return;
    }else{
        new_node->next=*H;
        new_node->prev=NULL;
        (*H)->prev=new_node;
    }
}

void Delete(struct node **H){
    if(*H!=NULL){
        struct node *temp = H;
        temp->next=NULL;
        printf("Deleting last element with value: %c\n",(*H)->data);
        *H=(*H)->next;
        free(temp);
    }else{
        printf("Empty list.\n");
    }
}

void DisplayF(struct node *H){
    int i = 0;
    if(H==NULL){printf("Empty list\n");return;};
    while(H!=NULL){
        i++;
        printf("Element #%d: %c\n",i, H->data);
        H=H->next;
    }
    return;
}
void DisplayB(struct node *H){
    int i = 0;
    if(H==NULL){printf("Empty list\n");return;};
    while(H!=NULL){
        i++;
        printf("Element #%d: %c\n",i, H->data);
        H=H->prev;
    }
    return;
}

void Search(struct node *H,char val){
    int i = 0;
    while(H!=NULL){
        i++;
        if(H->data==val){
            printf("Character '%c' was found in element %d\n",H->data,i);
            return;
        }
        H=H->next;
    }
    printf("The value you are looking for does not exist.\n");
}
int main(){
    struct node *head=NULL;
    int inp;
    char d;
    do{
        printf("1.Create\n2.Delete\n3.Display\n4.Search\n0.Exit\n");
        scanf("%d",&inp);
        switch (inp){
            case 1:
                printf("Enter the new node's character value: ");
                scanf(" %c",&d);
                Create(&head,d);
                break;
            case 2:
                Delete(&head);
                break;
            case 3:
                DisplayF(head);
                break;
            case 4:
                DisplayB(head);
            case 5:
                printf("What character do you want to search for? ");
                scanf(" %c",&d);
                Search(head,d);
                break;
            case 0:
                exit(0);
            default:
                printf("Enter a valid option from the menu below:\n");
                break;
        }

    }while(inp!=0);
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: The `Create` looks wrong. `new_node->next=*H;` will put the new_node in front of the old head. But the `H` is not changed. The head needs to be updated like : `*H = new_node`. There are possibly other problems but I didn't look beyond that. And you haven't really described a specific problem apart from "something is wrong". Please give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: In addition to that: on the first iteration, `*H` is `NULL`. Yet you attempt to access a member: `(*H)->prev`. You need to check if `*H` is not `NULL` and only then set its `prev` member.

Comment: And thirdly: `struct node *temp = H;` should be `struct node *temp = *H;`.

Comment: Lastly: the program doesn't exit but gets in a loop if you close the input stream.